# Jquery - Getting what actually is displayed in in text area

Tags: jquery, html

We are automating web tests and want to validate what is in the text area.

We want to check what is actually showing from a user perspective. It does not matter if it's placed there with placeholder or entered by user/testcase. We use the html5 placeholder attribute.

`$("textarea").text()` does not give me anything if the text has been entered via place holder.

Tried `$("textarea").val()` but it gives me the same behavior as using `.text()`.

We could write logic like `if ( text is empty ) { look at placeholder }` but that feels wrong since it would not determine what is actually showing in the text area. I would like to have an alternative to using the logic. Otherwise we assume that the browser uses the same logic that we implement in our test.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not read out the placeholder attribute via `.attr()` if the textarea is "empty"?

Comment: Hi @GungFoo. As explained in the question I would like to have an alternative to using the logic. If we do then we assume that the browser uses the same logic that we implement in our test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean html5 placeholder or placeholder added by js plugin?

if is case 1, i guess this can help:

```
var text = $("textarea").val() || $("textarea").attr('placeholder')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mJkFc/

Comment: Updated question to explain it's the html5 placeholder attribute we are talking about

Comment: It's not really what I wanted but I am using this for now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var t = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
var text = t.value || t.getAttribute("placeholder") || "";
```